# Invalid xml:base in Teamcity nuget feed

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I try to setup teamcity nuget feed. But when i try download package form nuget server i get next error in VS output window:

[image]

when i try get definition of nuget feed i see next:

[image]

in *Administration / Global settings / Server URL* i have valid dmin name of my server. How can i change xml:base attribute in feed definition?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an issue with TeamCity. From what I can see you are hosting TeamCity locally on your development machine and you are successfully downloading your own packages (1st picture). The error that you are seeing in chrome is absolutely fine.

However the issue that it appears you are having is that you have not configured either VisualStudio or your solution in VisualStudio to download from more than one place. The package that is failing is NancyFx which presumably you are not hosting from TeamCity so therefore you need to go and get it from the public NuGet Server. In order to achieve this you either have to configure VisualStudio or your solution file to search multiple package sources.

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/package-manager-ui#package-sources

Comment: NO, you wrong. I am hosting my teamcity in local Azure VM. Also, in VS i have setup two nuget feed: public and to my teamcityfeed. Also i can download list of nuget packages from my teamcity feed, but when i try download specific package i am rederecting to localhost:8080 (probably this address was setted up before i have changed to my current public domain). And about nancyFx: nancyfx was success downloaded as other dependency of my project, its not related to package in my nuget feed.

Comment: @SergeyShulik Sorry it was hard to see from the screen shots. Then the issue sounds like a routing issue between you local machine and your VM. You can change the base url that you want to use in the TeamCity admin.

Answer (score 0):

From [TeamCity support "Change base URL in FeedService"](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000059930-Change-base-URL-in-FeedService):

> It looks like you have a reverse proxy and it is not properly
>   configured. Please refer to TeamCity HowTo documentation about this:
>   https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=74845225#HowTo...-SetUpTeamCitybehindaProxyServer
>
> It seems HTTP proxy does not pass **Host header correctly**. When browser
>   makes a request it sets Host to hostname from browser address bar. If
>   proxy changes Host to something else, or removes it, then feed will
>   have URLs pointing to localhost, because TeamCity server does not know
>   that there is an HTTP proxy somewhere.
>
> Please check that HTTP proxy preserves original Host header.