# TeamCity NuGet Feed: Configure Feed URL

Tags: nuget, teamcity, feed, nuget-server

I'm attempting to set up my TeamCity instance as a private NuGet package feed. I have successfully configured the feed and set up a build that publishes artifacts.

However, I'm running into a problem when attempting to install a package in my source code from the TeamCity feed:

By going to the "NuGet Feed" page in TeamCity, I can see that the feed URL is
`http://localhost:8080/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/`.

I have set my local Visual Studio (running on my local machine, not the TeamCity server) as
`http://[my-TC-server]/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/`, and I can view the package in the NuGet manager with the expected attributes.

However, when I try to install the package, it fails because the src attribute in the package configuration is still set to `http://localhost:8080/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/download/NuGet_[myPackage]/73:id/p[myPackage].nupkg` (I can see this by viewing my TeamCity-hosted packages at `http://[my-TC-server]/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages()`), and the install fails because it is looking on my machine for the package file, and not on the TeamCity server. I assume the src attribute is set at pack time and grabbed from the TeamCity configuration somewhere.

If I navigate to to

`http://[my-TC-server]/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/download/NuGet_[myPackage]/73:id/p[myPackage].nupkg`

in a browser, I can successfully download the package.

Is it possible to configure the feed URL in TeamCity to be `http://[my-TC-server]/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/` so that the src param will also use `[my-TC-server]` instead of localhost? I can't find an option in TC to do this, and I haven't found any documentation for dealing with this problem.

If it is not possible to configure the feed URL, what would a good solution be so that my local machine can download the package from my TeamCity server?

Comment: OK, I realized that the NuGet feed URL is determined from the TeamCity server URL (Administration>General Settings). I set the server URL to be [my-TC-server], and now the feed URL looks how I'd expect. However, the packages are still being generated with a "localhost" source URL. I wonder if I'm running into a caching issue at this point?

Comment: I came across the use of GuestAuth, in the settings for TeamCity NugetFeed.
that lets any guest with the password/guest kombination have access, also if the psw is blank ;-)
Kenneth

Answer (score 3):

It was two things:

1. I needed to configure my TeamCity Server URL (Administration>General Settings)
2. I was running into [this problem with my server's reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658889/invalid-xmlbase-in-teamcity-nuget-feed), and running [this command on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841986/iis-aar-url-rewrite-for-reverse-proxy-how-to-send-http-host) fixed the problem (the server was not preserving the Host header in requests)

After those two, everything's all good!

Comment: Removing the feed and adding it again did the trick for me.  Thanks.